# Universal navigation bar in reusable UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UIViewController, which is the part of my static library. This UIViewController might be used in different Apps. Some Apps should be able to present this view in navigation style another using present modal.

The question is: what is the elegant way to design this UIViewController concerning the navigation bar? Currently I have the following solution:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.navigationController != nil) {
        self.navigationItem.title = @Test;
        //... set nav bar buttons

    } else {
        UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        navBar.topItem.title = @Test;
       //... set nav bar buttons and add UINavigationBar to view
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

well the **elegant** way would be to add your universal UIViewController to the UINavigationController

Its pretty useful that way.

Comment: I have thought about that, but in this case I'll need to forward my delegates from UIViewController to new UINavigationController. Is there any other solution perhaps? :)

Comment: why would need to forward delegates?

Comment: Currently it is used in such a way:
MyViewController *myController = // alloc init;
myController.delegate = self
With new NavController:
I will need to forward this delegate from MyViewController to NavController, so that API User can use it in the same way:
NavController *navController = // alloc init;
navController.delegate = self

Comment: Still not getting it. I use view controllers from static libs all the time

Comment: Look my comment above one more time, I have accidentally tapped the enter button :)

Comment: Dont see who the consumer is .delegate properties are visible to everyone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15189/discussion-between-le-coeur-and-stackmonster)

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 5 Apple added UIViewController containers. This allows you to write classes that behave like UINavigation Controllers.

You use the addChildViewController: method to add another view controller to your hierarchy, you can then draw the views of the View Controllers however you want.

This page of Apple's docs has all the information you need http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html